# -bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions

I have an Ubuntu(16.4) server which is accessible via putty(No GUI configured)

Yesterday I changed the `/usr/bin` permissions from the default `755` to `750` and now I am unable to change it back.

Command entered (as root):

```
chmod 750 /bin
```

The problem is, I am unable to login as root and can't do `sudo su`, can't change directory permissions, can't make any changes, can't use recovery method from grub to change the file permission.

Every time I enter some command it throws an error:

```
-bash: /usr/lib/ command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied.
```

Reverting back to 755 might help but I am unable to run `chmod`.

Please help...

Comment: Why you would do this is beyond me.... Trying booting off the install medium and rather than installing mount the folder and change permissions back